# How to check if value entered in Material ui textfield is an <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, material-ui

I am using TextField material-ui component in my code. I want to check if the value entered by user is an iframe. How I can do that? I am using ReactJS.

I am using `window.parent.frames.length > 0;` to check if page has an `iframe` but it is not working for `TextField` case. I want to handle this case on `onChange` not on page level, it seems like `window.parent.frames.length > 0;` works on page level. I want the have a check inside my `onChange` in the `TextField`

Here is my code:

```
<TextField
    label="Enter iframe"
    variant="outlined"
    onChange={({ target }) => {
        const value = target.value;
    
        //I want to check if `value` is an iframe
        handleChange(value)

    }}
    multiline
/>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to check if the input value contains an iframe with something like

```js
const containsIframeRE = /<iframe(?: [^>]*?)?(?:\/>|>.*?<\/iframe>)/i;

if (containsIframeRE.test(inputValue)) alert("Iframe found!");
```

You can see the regex working and play with it on https://regex101.com/r/uMfLFS/1